# Как добраться до вложенного свойства объекта в цикле?

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
top_obj = {
    nest_obj1: {
        prop: 'value'
    },
    nest_obj2: {
        prop: 'another value'
    }
}

for(key in top_obj){
    console.log(key.prop); // undefined
}
console.log(top_obj.nest_obj1.prop); // а так - всё нормально
```

Как же мне добраться до вложенного свойства в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К свойствам можно обращаться еще через скобки

```
top_obj['nest_obj1']
```

Получается мы можем передать в скобки переменную.
А key в цикле это ключ объекта, а не вложенный объект, поэтому надо

```
top_obj[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная цикла `key` - это не указатель на свойство, это строка, содержащая имя свойства.

```js
top_obj = {
  nest_obj1: {
    prop: 'value'
  },
  nest_obj2: {
    prop: 'another value'
  }
}

for (key in top_obj) {
  console.log(top_obj[key].prop);
}
```